# VSelect - selection not working with custom "item" slot in Vuetify 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I am using VSelect from Vuetify 3 in my Vue 3 app and I am trying to use item slot. But my VSelect options become unpickable

I have this VSelect element:

```
 <v-select
    v-model="tag"
    :items="tags"
    variant="solo"
    label="Tags" >
    <template #item="{ item }" >
      <v-list >
        <v-list-item :title="item.title" />
      </v-list>
    </template>
  </v-select>
```

tag and tags in data:

```
  tag: null,
  tags: [
    { title: 'example1', value: 0 },
    { title: 'example2', value: 1 },
  ],
```

in the output I have this select with options, but options are not pickable:

[image: output]

So how can I set a slot "item" to VSelect component in Vuetify 3 with pickable options?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `props` object handed to the slot contains an `onClick` callback, and you need to bind it in order for selection to work:

```html
<template #item="{ item, props: { onClick } }" >
  <v-list-item :title="item.title" @click="onClick"/>
</template>
```

The [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#slots-item) is a bit sparse at the moment and gives the type as `Record<string, unknown>`. In Vuetify 3.4, the other values are `key`, `title`, `value` and `ref`, a template ref from the underlying [VVritualScroll](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/virtual-scroller/) used to update height of the scroller.

When using a component with a `title` prop (like [VListItem](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-list-item/#props-title)), you can just bind the whole `props` object:

```html
<template #item="{ props }" >
  <v-list-item v-bind="props"/>
</template>
```

(Btw. the `#item` slot already renders its content into a `v-list`, there is no need to wrap it again)

Here it is in a snippet:

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify
const vuetify = createVuetify()
createApp({
  setup(){
    
    return {
       tag: ref(null),
        tags: [
          { title: 'example1', value: 0 },
          { title: 'example2', value: 1 },
        ],
    }
  }
}).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.6/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app" class="d-flex justify-center">
  <v-app>
    <div>
    <v-select
      style="width: 300px;"
      v-model="tag"
      :items="tags"
      variant="solo"
      label="Tags"
    >
      <template #item="{ item, props: {onClick, title, value} }" >
        <v-list-item :title="item.title"  @click="onClick"/>
      </template>
    </v-select>
      
      Selected: {{tag}}
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.6/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
```